# What is the purpose of Mage_Core_Block_Template_Facade

Tags: magento

After stumbling upon the following class while looking at magento source code: Mage_Core_Block_Template_Facade, i have absolutely no idea what this class does.

Obviously i have looked at it and investigated a little bit but it just is not clear to me.

Can anyone explain its purpose in life and when it might be useful to use

Comment: I've tried to parse through all that a few times, and I've never quite been able to understand what it's there for.  That said, there's some commentary on it in this comment thread http://www.pulsestorm.net/nofrills-layout-chapter-five that might make sense to you (I couldn't quite follow what Mr. Masy was on about, but it might might sense to you)

Comment: Im not sure what that comment was getting at :) - I have answered with my thoughts on the facade block.  Could have probably explained it a little better but hopefully it gets the point across

Comment: @DrewHunter Just pointing Stephen towards a place to start researching things — it wasn't worth a an actual answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry, i think you misunderstood me: not your comment - but  the comment from Mr Masey on the link you provided :) I think you were right to post it, definitely, as there is actually very little on subject anywhere else.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Mage_Core_Block_Template_Facade](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template/Facade.php), is actually quite simple to understand. It..

- Allows a value to be set on the block
- Allows layout to specify an attribute/value from a registry object to be set on the block
- Allows the equality of the two values above to be evaluated

Essentially, this is what makes the Facade Block different from other blocks - the interaction with the registry and comparing a registry key/value with a block instance key/value - all from layout xml.

There is only one example of the block being used in core code...

Looking in [catalog.xml](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml#L241) and [product/view.phtml](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml) you will see **container1** and **container2** blocks - they are both identical, but only one is ever rendered in the final output.

So why are they both there?  This will explain how Mage_Core_Block_Template_Facade works.

Core is using the facade block as a method to allow the product options block position within [product/view.phtml](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml) (not within the layout, but within the template itself) to be configurable from in the admin area. If you look in the design tab whilst editing a product, you should notice the last option: "Display Product Options In" - the two dropdown values correlate each to the container1 and container2 blocks that you can see in catalog.xml and view.phtml.  Specifically, looking in [product/view.phtml](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml) you should see container1 and container2 positioned in different divs.

Layout decides which of these blocks to display based on the value set in "Display Product Options In" using the facade block.

Here is how it works...

---

Check catalog.xml and you will see:

```
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
</block>
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
</block>
<action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
<action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
```

**setDataByKey**

```
<action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
```

This sets an identifier for this block that will be evaluted against the registry object.  In the context of the options containers, this value will have to match one of the dropdown values in the admin area mentioned previously.

**setDataByKeyFromRegistry**

```
<action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
```

Tells the block "hey, when we need to look at product object in the registry and grab the value of the options_container key/attribute". Akin to: `Mage::registry('product')->getData('options_container');`

We would expect this value to be container1 or container2 in this specific example.

**ifEquals**

Finally, ifEquals is called in conjunction with unsetCallChild to remove the container not selected in the admin area.

using container1 as an example...

```
<action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
```

this calls the ifEquals method on that block instance, if the return value is 0 then container1 will be unset and not rendered.